# DDD: Cannot convert string "-*-helvetica-medium-r-*-230-*-iso8859-*" to type FontStruct

Tags: c++, linux, debugging, gdb, ddd-debugger

I'm using DDD 3.3.12 to debug C/C++.The following is the OS infos:

> RHEL6.0-2012-x86_64
>   Red Hat Enterprise Linux Workstation release 6.3

When I started DDD, it shows:

> Warning: Cannot convert string "-*-helvetica-medium-r-*-*-*-230-*-*-*-*-iso8859-*" to type FontStruct
>   (Annoyed?  Try 'Edit->Preferences->General->Suppress X Warnings'!)
>   Warning: Cannot convert string "-*-helvetica-medium-r-*-*-*-200-*-*-*-*-iso8859-*" to type FontStruct
>   Warning: Cannot convert string "-*-helvetica-bold-r-*-*-*-230-*-*-*-*-iso8859-*" to type FontStruct
>   Warning: Cannot convert string "-*-helvetica-medium-*-*-*-*-230-*-*-*-*-iso8859-*" to type FontStruct
>   Warning: Cannot convert string "-*-helvetica-bold-*-*-*-*-230-*-*-*-*-iso8859-*" to type FontStruct
>   Warning: Cannot convert string "-*-helvetica-bold-r-*-*-*-340-*-*-*-*-iso8859-*" to type FontStruct
>   Warning: Cannot convert string "-*-symbol-*-*-*-*-*-230-*-*-*-*-adobe-*" to type FontStruct

After I tried

> 'Edit->Preferences->General->Suppress X Warnings'!

Those warnings disappeared.

I changed the Font of DDD before. How can I avoid these warnings? Change the Font to default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The warnings appears because the fonts selected by you are not supported by DDD yet.

In your DDD, select

> Edit->Preferences->Fonts

And, change all thing to the default like below:

[image]

Then，no warning will appear.

Comment: hi, I'm experiencing the same. with default font information(as you suggested). Ubuntu 16.04.5 fresh install. Any suggestions? Thanks!